# Regex not valid in google sheets error?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas

I tried to use

```
([^\u0000-\uFFFF])
```

to find emojis but google sheets says its not a valid regular expression i tried it on rubular.com it works. what is wrong with it then? [image]

test string

```
   almfla snflk a lkanfl - = ; ' &*)^%$#!  cmk
```

it should return

Comment: Are you using it in a Google script or one of the regex functions?

Comment: as part of a regex function

Comment: this works `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"([^u0000-uFFFF])")` but returns only one element

Comment: You may want to check this [support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en), a quick guide on using regex function in google sheets. Also Google products use RE2 for regular expressions. you can check on the link to learn more on [how to use RE2 expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). Hope this helps.

Comment: What formula do you used?

Comment: @Rubén i used regexmatch(); i figured out the problem i changed the u to x so i was just syntax

Comment: Please post an answer with the solution that you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ([^\u0000-\uFFFF]) -> ([^\x0000-\xFFFF])

test string

```
   There are 3 emojis

=REGEXEXTRACT(I26, "([^\x0000-\xFFFF]*)")
```

returns